# Multiple File Support in Google Drive API is not working any more

Tags: google-drive-api

We are using "Multiple File Support" ("Allow users to open multiple files using a single instance of this application" checkbox in Google APIs Console) to allow our users to tick multiple files in Google Drive and open them on a single page. 
However this feature seems to stop working recently. It looks like the second file ID is not passed in the URL any more.

For example, if I tick two files, the redirect URL still contains a single ID in the state parameter:

```
{"ids":["0B7r4-DNJuWqNT0hhb0lxMnhtZ0k"],"action":"open","userId":"USER_ID"}
```

Has something changed related to the way of opening multiple files at a time?